# why $\exp({1\over-x^2})$ is not real analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[Real analytic function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) Can someone explain why $\exp({1\over-x^2})$ is not real analytic? i have read a book talking about smoothness of functions and it talks about this function is not real analytic but don't quite get it.

Comment: What are the derivatives at zero?

Comment: Ahh, Jeopardy...

Comment: @copper.hat Is that $f^{(q)}=0$ so the taylor serier doesn't converge to $f(h)$?

Comment: The Taylor series is just zero, which only matches at $x=0$. See Ittay's answer & comments...

Answer (score 3):

To be real analytic the function needs to be developable in a power series with positive radius at every point of its domain. This is not the case for this function at the point $0$. It is a classic exercise (I believe this example goes back to Cauchy) to verify that the Taylor expansion of this function at $x=0$ is constantly $0$ (all you have to do is compute the derivatives of the function at $x=0$ and show they are all equal to $0$). Since the function is clearly not identically $0$ at any neighborhood of $0$, it follows that the function is not a power series with positive radius at $x=0$, thus not real analytic.

Comment: Do you mean that $f^{(q)}=0 \forall q$ while f(h)not equal to $0$  if $h$ is not (0) so the taylor serier doesn't converge to $f(h)$?

Comment: I mean that $f^{q}(0)=0$ for all integer $q\ge0$, but $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\ne 0$, so that that the Taylor series does not converge to the function at any point except $x=0$.

Comment: But the OP did not even define the function at x=0.